# SetCursorPos() and SetWindowPos() on different machines

Tags: c++, resolution

I tried around with SetCursorPos() and SetWindowPos() and it worked well in my desktop at home. But when I use it on my laptop (on a presized window) it's not on the, for example, same radio button like on my desktop at home.

Now is it because of the resolution? So basically my question is: How can I use SetWindowPos() and SetCursorPos() that it works on other machines as well? Is it even possible?

EDIT: Just have noticed that both, my laptop and my desktop have a resolution of 1920 x 1080. So why is there a difference?

Comment: by getting the screen resolution and calculating the individual value that you need to have it at the same position this should be simple to achieve.

Comment: Hey, have a look at my edit in the main post, both, my laptop and my desktop have a resolution of 1920 x 1080.

Comment: How are you calculating the position of the cursor?

Comment: I am not calculating anything. I just use for example 

`SetCursorPos(440,300);` for the cursor position and
`SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, NULL);`
for the window position as I assumed that, with the same resolution, there wouldn't be any difference, but there is.

Comment: Have to add something: One machine runs on Win8 and the oder on Win7. Could the difference come from not equal borders?